# Counting the edge points of an image in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

I have detected the edge points of  an image as shown in the following image:
[image]

then i have divided the image into different blocks of the same size as shown here:
[image]

Now what i want is to count the number of edge points in every image block.

Can someone please let me know how to do that

your assistance is much appreciated

Comment: For each block, use `nnz`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming that by the edge points you mean white pixels, on black backround, you can do something along these lines:

```
   % some random block, simulating your case
>> a_blk = rand(10,5)-0.5;
   % edge pixels are greater than 0 (as a assume).
>> sum(sum(a_blk>0))
```

Comment: Please try `sum(a_blk(:)>0)`, as this saves you one sum. This gives me a speed-up of about a factor of 100.

Comment: @hbaderts - Nice catch, and I agree.